# How to delete data in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem to delete data in nuxtjs:

```
  <tr v-for="(user, index) in paginatedUsers">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#" @click="deleteUser(index)">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
```

```
       deleteUser(index){
         this.$axios.$delete(`/users/` + this.users.data[index].id)
          .then(({data}) =>{
            this.users.data.splice(index, 1);
          })
          .catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors);
          });
      },
```

when click on any of the items, get the following error

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
OR
`Cannot read property '12' of undefined`

how solve this error

Comment: it is giving you undefined because you don't have any data in this.users variable try printing it and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
this.$axios.$delete(`/users/${this.users[index].id}`)
...
```